# SlidingDrawer BottomOffset doesn't work

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a SlidingDrawer inside a relativeLayout.
Below that relativeLayout I have another LinearLayout as "included layout".
problem is that the SlidingDrawer covers the whole screen and pushes the bottom layout out of the screen.

setting bottomOffset on the slidingDrawer indeed raises it up, but the content of the drawer is not pushed above.

how can that be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: can't figure it out without some code.